# Saving a current open file using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Hi I am having trouble saving currently open files with JFileChooser.  I understand how to save a new file using showSaveDialog but I want to open a file in JFileChooser, edit it and save it to the existing file I have opened instead of it opening a save as menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EditorFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * @field serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private  JTextArea textArea;

    private  JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir")); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EditorFrame frame = new EditorFrame();
        frame.init();       
    }

    private void init(){
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Editor");
        this.setContentPane(createContentPanel());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    /**
     * @return
     * @return Container
     */
    private  Container createContentPanel() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        jPanel.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jPanel.add(createButton(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return jPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     * @return Component
     */
    private  Component createButton() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        jPanel.add(openButton);
        jPanel.add(saveButton);
        openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int state = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (state == 0) { 
                    File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        String textString = readText(new FileInputStream(f), "utf-8");
                        textArea.setText(textString);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                }           
            }
        });
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                writeText(textArea.getText(),jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
        return jPanel;
    }
    private  String readText(final InputStream in, String charset) {
        if (charset == null) {
            charset = Charset.defaultCharset().toString();
        }
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, charset));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
    private void writeText(final String text, final String descPath) {
        File root = new File(descPath.substring(0, descPath.lastIndexOf('\\')));
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            // BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new
            // FileWriter(descPath));
            BufferedWriter bw =
                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(descPath), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            bw.write(text);
            bw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was saying like I have a Gui that has open,save as and save, but i want to add an action for the menu button save which would just let you save the text file that you just edited without opening up the showSaveDialog.

Comment: For save it, get the exists file path and the new text data , then write the text to file.

Comment: any chance you can give me an example? I tried doing that but it keeps going to the exception. this is what my attempt is ` try{
                BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                String textArea = frame.getTextArea().getText();
                fileWriter.write(textArea);
                fileWriter.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot Save File");
                }`

Comment: Which exception, may something you missing.